# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listdir'"

Tags: python-2.7

```
def getfilename():
    prefixed = [filename for filename in os.listdir(filelocation) if filename.startswith("V")] 
    print prefixed
    return prefixed
```

Above function gives me an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listdir'

Please help me resolve it

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting the exception, is because you have set `os` to `None` somewhere else in your code; and `os` is the name of a built-in library.

Either way, your code duplicates the functionality of the built-in `glob` method; so just use that:

```
import glob
import os

filelocation = '/path/to/the/directory'

def get_filename():
   return glob.glob(os.path.join(filelocation, 'V*'))
```

Comment: It is best to use available library routines than implementing your own.